# Одна кнопка и лайка и дизлайка

Tags: jquery, button, like

```
.like-buttons
  .liked
  button.like
    span.countd 12

$('.like').click(function(){
     let like = $(this). closest('.countd').html();
     like = like + 1;
});
```

У меня есть кнопка, надо бы сделать так, чтобы при щелчке на неё цифра увеличивалась на 1, а при повторном щелчке - уменьшалась на 1, и так далее по кругу.

https://codepen.io/Void0000/pen/oNzGmGr

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (this.classList.contains('up'))
    this.textContent = parseInt(this.textContent) + 1;
  else
    this.textContent = parseInt(this.textContent) - 1;
    
  this.classList.toggle("up");
});
```

```css
.btn {
    width:      100px;
    height:     50px;
    
    border:     none;
    background: #bb0000;
    color:      white;
    
    cursor:     pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
    background: #d00000;
}

.btn.up {
    background: #00bb00;
}

.btn.up:hover {
    background: #00d000;
}
```

```html
<button class = 'btn up'>1</button>
```

Comment: Просто немного короче: `document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.textContent = +!e.target.classList.toggle("up") + 1;
});`

Comment: @Deonis и что оно делает? пишет 1 или 2 для первой кнопки в DOM?